# Get multiple values from array fetch

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I am sending a get request to a api where the values are inside a array.

I want to get multiple values simultaneously.
How can I do this other than using index to get specific key values?

For example below, I want every result of `results.data.message.body.artist_list.[4].artist.artist_name` but don't want to have to use  index `[4]`.

```
methods: {
   fetchMusic(e) {
     if (e.key === 'Enter') {
       // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
       axios.get('  ... ', {
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          },
        })
          .then((response) => response).then(this.setResults);
      }
    },
    setResults(results) {
      this.artists = results.data.message.body.artist_list.[4].artist.artist_name;
      this.artistname = results.data.message.body.artist_list[0].artist.artist_name;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thanks for any inputs on my code

Comment: What exactly do you want? If I understand you correct you want to have a array of artist_names? Just use a map on the array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to fetch an API and display it's info by looping on the items: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-currying-nsoo3?file=/src/App.vue

Basically, get the results (an array so), then loop on each iteration of this array and display the wished data accordingly with something like

```html
<div v-for="result in fetchedResults" :key="result.id">
  <p>
    <span>Name: {{ result.username }}</span> ~
    <span>email: {{ result.email }}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Btw, don't forget the `key`, it's important. More info [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State) about this point.
Official documentation's examples on [how to loop on an array](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for).

Comment: but that is if I want different values, I want every artist_name in every object, in the array. how would I do that? thanks

Comment: Could your share us an example array? Not sure I get what you're saying here.